# POST error with Angular.js

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, model-view-controller, controller

I'm currently trying to build a webshop for whisky using laravel and angular.js. I was trying to simply add a product to my basket but I keep having the same errors in my console. I wanted to just put my product_id and my basket_id in the 'basket_product' column. For now I want to put the product_id in the basket with id 3.

I've been stuck on this issue for days now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

**these are the errors:**

[image]

This is my '**BasketController.php**'

```
class BasketController extends Controller
{ 
    public function index()
    {
        return Basket::join('basket_product', 'baskets.id', '=', 'basket_product.basket_id')->get();

    }
    public function create()
    {

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'basket_id' => 'required|integer',
            'product_id' => 'required|integer',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);
        $basket = new Basket($request->only(['basket_id', 'product_id']));

        if ($basket->save()) {
            return response()
                ->json($basket)
                ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
        }
    }

    public function show()
    {

    }

}
```

This is my '**product.controller.js**'

```
vm.$$ix = {
            save : createBasketItemAction
        };

vm.item = {
          basket_id: 3, 
          products_id: $state.params.id

        };

switch ($state.current.name) {
            case 'products.grid':
                vm.products = getProductsAction();
                vm.categories = getCategoryAction();
                break;
            case 'products.show':
                vm.categories = getCategoryAction();
                vm.product = getProductAction();
                vm.$$ix.save = createBasketItemAction;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

 function createBasketItemAction() {
            $log.info(createBasketItemAction.name, 'post:', vm.item);

            return BasketResource
                .save(vm.item, success, error);

            function error(error) {
                $log.error(createBasketItemAction.name, 'ERROR', 'error:', error);
            }

            function success(resource, responseHeader) {
                $log.log(createBasketItemAction.name, 'SUCCESS', 'resource:', resource, 'responseHeader:', responseHeader());
                $state.go('blog.posts');
            }
        }
```

This is the line of code I used to fire the post event in my '**product.view.html**'

```
<md-button ng-click="vm.$$ix.save()" ng-disabled="postForm.$invalid">Add to Basket</md-button>
```

And finally, this is my '**basket-resource.service.js**'

```
;(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.basket')
        .factory('BasketResource', BasketResource);

    /* @ngInject */
    function BasketResource(
        // Angular
        $cacheFactory,
        $resource,
        // Custom
        UriService
    ) {
        var url = UriService.getApi('basket_products');


        var paramDefaults = {

        };

        var actions = {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
        };

        return $resource(url, actions);
    }

})();
```

This is how my database is built:

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to enable the CORS with laravel : http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/

Comment: I had already done this but I did it again just to make sure. I'm having the same error.